# bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord

I got this error after running the code:
File "C:\BOT Music\BM.py", line 8, in 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BotBase.**init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
I have tried over and over again many of the methods that Bard AI suggests but the above error always appears
and this is my code copied from AI Bard:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

import discord_py_opus

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("...")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.voice = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, token=DISCORD_TOKEN)

youtube = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey=os.getenv("DEVELOPER_KEY"))

current_song = None

opus = discord_py_opus.OpusEncoder()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")
....

bot.run()`
```

I hope it can be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bard knows very little. Always check the docs after you use AI, AI can hallucinate rather easily.

I cannot test your code or reproduce the error because it is a somewhat involved process to get a discord token.

Perusing the [docs on Command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) and the [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=token), I have noticed some things.

- Neither [Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) nor its superclass [Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client) take an API token. The token is used in the [login](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.login) function however.
- The docs on command say you really really need to set `intents.message_content = True`.

I also notice a stray backtic (`) in your code at the end, something AIs like bard put at the end of code examples a lot because code often occurrs in markdown blocks. This should also be removed.

I know this isn't much of an answer, but it's the best I've got under the circumstances.